# This is sometype of weird audio thing it's hard to explain

Tags: audio

Okay so basically I was trying to get my speakers to work, but I got tired of trying and gave up. But here's where the problem comes in, now my headsets aren't working either. And it's this weird glitch or something, I don't know how to explain it. The best example I can give is whenever I try to do anything watch a video play a game or anything like that. you can hear the background of whatever I'm watching, like for example the walking the final season I can hear all the gunshots, the birds chirping, and the leaves wrestling and all that, but whenever they go to speak I can't hear them speak, like there's no voice to them. And it's not just with games, it's with everything. If I try to pop in a movie in my computer and watch it the same thing happens, I can't hear anyone speaking in the movie, but I can hear all the sound effect.footsteps and everything. And I don't know why can someone please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Does your computer have different audio outputs?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've got a bad "earth" (common) connection and all the audio you hear became *monophonic difference* of stereo channels. This effectively cancels out all center material, leaving you with just what is panned to the side. Also if you try to hear music, you'll have much less bass that there must be.

Voice and bass are often placed in the center of the stereo panoram, so they are being cut this way. This is exactly the way "voice cancellers" work: they just subtract channels.

Check "ground" connection.

Comment: In less technical terms, it's a physical connection issue. Try to use these headphones with a different device. If the issue persists, the cable or plug is at fault. If it doesn't, the socket is bad.

Comment: I'll even extend. Often headsets have 1/8" TRS jack, and those with microphone have 1/8" TRRS jack (with two rings). TRS have a "S" for a ground, "T" for left channel and "R" for right. But TRRS has usually "T" for a microphone, first "R" for ground. So if socket is physically constructed like it expects "S" to be a common, a headset with the microphone and a TRRS jack may errorneously work like described.

Comment: So I checked and the headset does work with other devices. So that means the socket would have to be bad. The thing I'm confused about though is it was working fine before I switch my speakers and messed around with them to give them working. I didn't start happening until I switch the headset back.

Comment: I'll disassemble the socket just for curiosity. It is constructed like a spring-loaded lamel pressed against the jack. One of these lamels might have been broken. Try to remember if you excercised more-than-usual forces when connecting or pulling a jack, or if you heard some strange clicks.